# Contradiction in Fourier analysis of differential equation - what rules did I break?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'm interested in the Fourier Spectrum of the solution of the differential equation on the domain $t \in [0, \infty]$:

$$ \frac{dp}{dt} = -\beta p $$

Doing Fourier Analysis on this differential equation I get:

$$ (i \omega + \beta ) P = 0 $$

which is interesting because this would seem to indicate that there are only trivial solutions to this equation.

The time domain solution to this equation is:

$$ p(t) = p(0) e^{-\beta  t} \quad \text{for } t \geq 0$$

If I take the fourier transform of this I get:

$$ P (\omega) = \int_{0}^{\infty} p(0) e^{-\beta t} e^{-i\omega t} dt = p(0) \int_{0}^{\infty}   e^{-(i\omega + \beta) t} dt $$

$$ P(\omega) = - \frac{p(0)}{i\omega + \beta} e^{-(i\omega + \beta) t} \big |^{t=\infty}_{t = 0} = \frac{p(0)}{i\omega + \beta} $$

Now I plut this into my original equation:

$$ (i \omega + \beta) P = (i \omega + \beta)  \frac{p(0)}{i \omega + \beta} = p(0) \neq 0 $$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I have came across some similiar problems always by *homogeous* ODE's. The same problem occurs when you are using a Laplace transform. I am not sure but I would claim that integral transforms are somehow not able to solve homogeous ODE's ore you have to consider that $\mathcal{F}_t\{0\}(\omega)=c$.

Comment: hmmm, using the Laplace transform the answer actually pops out because $L\{\frac{dp}{dt}\} = sL\{p\}  - p(0)$, which gives the equation $(s + \beta)L\{p\} = p(0)$ which is correct if $s = i\omega$. Why didn't this work for Fourier?

Comment: Oh, then my mind fooled me. Yes, you are right concerning this and I know where I did wrong on my problem. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you take the Fourier transform over all of $\mathbb R,$ but in the second case you take it only over the positive half of $\mathbb R.$

If we limit $p(t)$ to be non-zero only for $t>0$ then the first Fourier transform becomes
$$
\mathcal{F}\{LHS\} 
= \int_0^\infty p'(t) \, e^{-i\omega t} \, dt \\
= [p(t) \, e^{-i\omega t}]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty p(t) \, (-i\omega) e^{-i\omega t} \, dt \\
= -p(0) + i\omega \int_0^\infty p(t) e^{-i\omega t} \, dt \\
= -p(0) + i\omega P(\omega)
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{F}\{RHS\} 
= \int_0^\infty (-\beta p(t)) \, e^{-i\omega t} \, dt \\
= -\beta \int_0^\infty p(t) \, e^{-i\omega t} \, dt \\
= -\beta P(\omega)
$$

Thus,
$$(i\omega+\beta)P(\omega) = p(0)$$
so
$$P(\omega) = p(0)/(i\omega+\beta).$$

This is the same as you got in the second case.

Comment: could you elaborate? I see the conceptual difference but I don't see how it changes the answer.

Comment: The normal Fourier integrals, without the restriction $t\in[0,\infty]$, looks like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{ix\cdot y}\mathrm{d}x$ and from this one the correspondance tables are computed. Therefore, if you use a different transform, in this case $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{ix\cdot y}\mathrm{d}x$ you will get a different solution I guess

Comment: @MikeFlynn. I have now added some calculations.